# What is the term for 3D printing, the kind with red and blue glasses?

Tags: 3d, terminology

I've been trying to find a a company that can print our invitations in 3D. When I Google it, it only shows me "pop-up" invitations which is not what I'm looking for.

Is there a better term to search for when trying to find someone that can print party invitations in 3D (the kind you need the red and blue glasses to read)? If you know of any companies that do it and ship to Canada that would be great too.

Thanks :)
Nadia

Comment: For the record: '3D printing' is printing actual physical objects that you can pick up and touch. This is a different term than printing images than can be viewed in 3D.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The red-blue or actually red-cyan 3D is known as [Anaglyph 3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_3D). It is formed by superimposing two pictures from different view angles multiplied by a read and magenta filter.

Any offset printer should be able to print the image in most printers just as long as you can do the color separation yourself.

Comment: I have no idea where to begin to do the color separation as this is not my field of expertise at all :-/ The printers that I have contacted all told me they were unable to do this.

Comment: The wiki link tells you: overlay two images, remove all red from one (leaving it blue/cyan), remove blue+green from the other (leaving it red). Set the layer(s) to "screen" blend mode. Obviously, you need two images of the same thing taken from two viewpoints, simulating your own eye positions. This can be achieved with a tripod, a ruler, two iphones and some duck-tape. Joojaas point is: once the image is made, there is no "special printer" you need to locate.

Comment: http://mars.nasa.gov/mer/spotlight/3d01.html

Comment: well  capturing the 2 images might not be as trivial as you think. But it really depends on things... if yoir using a 3d app its easy enough.  Anyway You may want to shop for the glasses first.